# How to disable dragging of viewer?

Tags: javascript, openseadragon

I had a feature which can get current pointer color like photoshop. I've used `setMouseNavEnabled` to disable drag, but it also can't scroll.

Does any way can only disable the drag event? Or enable scroll when `setMouseNavEnabled = false` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

```
tracker = new $.MouseTracker({
        element: this.viewer.canvas,
        pressHandler: setMouseNavEnabled(false),
        releaseHandler: setMouseNavEnabled(true),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's other ways to disable dragging:

```
    // Using viewer events
    viewer.addHandler('canvas-drag', (event) => {
      event.preventDefaultAction = true;
    });

    // Similar code can be used for the following viewer events:
    //   'canvas-key', 'canvas-scroll', 'canvas-click',
    //   'canvas-double-click', and 'canvas-drag'
```

```
    // For specific pointer devices
    viewer.gestureSettingsMouse.dragToPan = false;
    viewer.gestureSettingsTouch.dragToPan = true;
    viewer.gestureSettingsPen.dragToPan = true;
```